# Error in building own kernel with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling

We are using Ubuntu 20.04 and building our own kernel using the following link. site:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

#commands:

```
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
// quicker build:

LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch

After entering above command below error comes in kernel compilation.


make[4]: *** [/home/embed/workspace/Intel_3930/custom5/custom4/disco/scripts/Makefile.build:515: drivers/net/ethernet] Error 2
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [/home/embed/workspace/Intel_3930/custom5/custom4/disco/scripts/Makefile.build:515: drivers/net] Error 2
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [/home/embed/workspace/Intel_3930/custom5/custom4/disco/Makefile:1103: drivers] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/embed/workspace/Intel_3930/custom5/custom4/disco/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:173: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/embed/workspace/Intel_3930/custom5/custom4/disco'
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:50: /home/embed/workspace/Intel_3930/custom5/custom4/disco/debian/stamps/stamp-build-generic] Error 2
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Ajay

Comment: What kernel version are you trying to compile? Did you successfully compile it before making any changes? I think your actual error was earlier than you listed, try to find it (sometimes is can be way back in the spew of stuff to the terminal). What does Makefile line 1103 say?

Comment: Hi Doug Smythies, Thanks for reply. We are using kernel version 5.13.0-37-generic and ubuntu 21.10. No before we are not compiled successfully. any other suggestion regarding this issue.

Comment: Yes, edit your question adding the actual error, and with what line 1103 of the Makefile says.